# Saving xml in an xml.element

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

I am writting a program which calls a `webservice`. One parameter I need to give the webservice is an xml.element.

The problem is that I don't know how I create one? i am absolute noob in xml. But I have the xml code I need to give the webservice. I am just to stupid to get it in an xml.element variable.

I already tried to find a solution on google, but nothing exactly fit.

I think the xml string needs just to put in the xml.element.

Comment: Please add the desired XML output and the signature of the WebService.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information, but this should get you started. Here's how to create an XElement and pass a variable into `<child2>`:

```
Imports System.Xml

Dim myVar = "sometext"
Dim myXMLElement as XElement = 
                          <parent>
                              <child1>text</child1>
                              <child2><%= myVar =></child2>
                              <child3>text</child3>
                          </parent>
```

See [XML in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384833.aspx) for more information.